# Memcached: Replace or let expire?

Tags: php, caching, memcached

Is it bad practise to create a new key for an updated result set instead of replacing the existing key?

I'd like use the method of appending a "version" (ex. a timestamp) to the end of some of my keys rather replacing the existing one.

This approach will rely on the built-in allocation of space (expiry/LRU). Is that ok, or will it mean a significant hit on performance?

Answer (score 2):

less recently used keys are deleted when memcache starts running out of memory. i.e if you have 100MB of memory and you use it all, the keys you haven't accessed or updated most recently will be deleted first.

from a performance standpoint imo you should be fine. memcache is very fast. although i don't personally understand why you would want to approach it with timestamp-based data unless you explain the application.

Comment: I don't think you understand my issue. I want to know whether it is responsible to rely on memcached removing old keys instead of replacing it when the data is updated.

Comment: I understand the issue, it's not a hit on performance to rely on LRU. Are you needing the old data for some other purpose though? If not, then why do you care to have timestamped keys in the first place?

Comment: I just have a few cases where I'd benefit from this structure code-wise. So I'd like to know whether it is an acceptable practice.

Comment: There is no performance hit from relying on the slab allocator for removing old keys. The locking overhead is low to remove an item from a slab and since everything is in memory this will happen very quickly.